# Android : Render a RadioButton and WebView inside a RadioGroup programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, radio-button, radio-group

I wish to render something like this inside a `RadioGroup`

(X) - (WebView)

(X) - (WebView)

(X) - (WebView)

(X) - (WebView)

*where (X) is the RadioButton*

The contents of WebView can be a very small formatted text, or an image.

I have written the following code

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup( getApplicationContext() );
radioGroup.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
{
    RadioButton optionRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
optionRadioButton.setLayoutParams( p );

    radioGroup.addView(optionRadioButton);

    WebView optionWebView = new WebView( getApplicationContext() );
    optionWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(URL, webViewData, "text/html", null, null);
    p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    optionWebView.setLayoutParams( p );
    radioGroup.addView( optionWebView );
}

ll.addView( radioGroup );
```

The output that I am getting is something like this.
(X)

(WebView)

(X)

(WebView)

(X)

(WebView)

(X)

(WebView)

I want the `RadioButton` and `WebView` to be displayed in the same line.

I have tried putting the `RadioButton` and `WebView` combination inside a `LinearLayout` container, that displays the text properly, but the `RadioGroup` functionality gets affected.

I have also tried to use something like

```
optionRadioButton.setText( Html.fromHtml( webViewData ) );
```

This thing is not working well when I try to send images in the webViewData.

I have also tried some things with gravity, setOrientation, but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something very basic here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do this way..   

 RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
            radioGroup.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                LinearLayout lnr=new LinearLayout(this);
                RadioButton optionRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                optionRadioButton.setLayoutParams(p);


                lnr.addView(optionRadioButton);

                WebView optionWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
                optionWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(URL, webViewData, "text/html", null, null);
                p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                optionWebView.setLayoutParams(p);
                lnr.addView(optionWebView);
                radioGroup.addView(lnr);

            }

            ll.addView(radioGroup);
```

Comment: As I said.. I tried this.. But by using this the functionality of the RadioGroup gets stops working.. I would have to write custom code to handle the radioGroup functionality.. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been Very long time since the question been asked. But Whoever comes to this page with same problem statement can check this method to solve the problem

I had the same Problem.
I solved it by using this beautiful library.

https://github.com/worker8/RadioGroupPlus#downloadinstall

Instead of Android's Radio group just use this library's Custom Radio group. It combines all the radio button inside this particular group and considers it as its own immediate child. So Even if it inside two levels no problem.

For all those who is compelled to use web view and radio button together can use this particular library.
cheers!